# Postgresql - CASE/WHEN with wrong return

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to use CASE/WHEN inside Postgresql to check two colums, but the results are odd.
As it's shown in the image below, all the lines where "gain_value" is 8 AND "patrimony_value" have a higher value return a wrong result.

This is my statement:

```
    select stop_value, gain_value, patrimony_value,
case
    when patrimony_value >= gain_value then 1
    else 2
end
from copy.copy_stop_gain csg
```

Since it's a pretty straightforwad "if/else", i'm really not sure what i could be doing wrong.
Can anyone show me where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I see that your column types are texts. Comparing text "8" with "103" is not same as number 8 with 103...

Answer (score 2):

Try casting string values to numbers (or perhaps change column type in schema)...

```
   select stop_value, gain_value, patrimony_value,
case
    when patrimony_value::INTEGER >= gain_value::INTEGER then 1
    else 2
end
from copy.copy_stop_gain csg
```

Comment: This is indeed my mistake, column types are text. Casting worked. Thank you!!

Comment: You will still be much better off changing the type to a numeric  type. While casting works when the data are proper numeric values eventually a non-numeric character will get into it, then your script aborts. Unless that column can legitimately contain non-numeric values in which case you need to validate for numeric values before casting.  Storing numeric values is always a bad idea and always causes eventual problems.